# @URLMappings annotation, the action will be used for each of the mappings

Tags: prettyfaces

hello I have two URL mappings in java class
one is calling on hyperlink and other is on button

on hyperlink I call

```
@URLAction(mappingId="abc")
//method..
private String hello(){
return null;
}
```

on button I call

```
@URLAction(mappingId="def")
//method..
private String hi(){
return null;
}
```

first time I call hello() on hyperlink it works fine
but when I call hi() on button it works fine too but hello() is also called

as in OCPSOFT
If the class the annotated method belongs to declares multiple URL mappings using the @URLMappings annotation, the action will be used for each of the mappings.
    http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html

my Question is that I want call one method on each urlmapping id any idea ??
thnks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit a JSF form by clicking something like a `<h:commandButton>`, JSF will always perform a postback, which means that the request will go back to the original page. That's why   your method is executed a second time. If you don't want this, you can configure PrettyFaces to skip page action method invocation for postback:

```
@URLAction(mappingId="abc", onPostback=false)
private String hello(){
    return null;
}
```